# asp:DropDownList width, fill parent

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a dropdownlist like this:

```
<asp:panel runat="server" groupingtext="Some Text">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><asp:DropDownList runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</asp:panel>
```

I want the dropdownlist's width to always fill the area of the parent regardless of the size of the items contained within. How can I do this?

Comment: `style="width: 100%;"`

Comment: This doesn't work with an empty list. The dropdownlist appears to take the size of the largest item in the list when I do this.

Comment: put the dropdownlist inside a div and set the div size. the dropdownlist will Always take the size of the div. looks weird but works

Comment: @CássioGalvão Well, I might as well set the width on the dropdownlist if I'm going to do that. I'm trying to get away from an absolute width. I want it to resize as the parent resizes.

Answer (score 0):

dropdownlist is rendered as `<select>` in html
so how about using css?
like

```
<td><asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="yourclasshere"/></td>

select.yourclasshere { width:100px }
```

Comment: The problem is the 100px. I want it to fill the parent so when the parent resizes, it does also.

Comment: then set it as 100%, but you do need specify your parent's width

Comment: Or give min-width a try.  select.yourclasshere { min-width:100px }